# cURL get html page result empty

Tags: php, html, url, curl

I have some code to that should get the webpage from a supplied url. The urls will look something like this:

> https://www.facebook.com/events/383049449109054/

This is the code i have for fetching the page:

```
function GetHtmlContents($url){
    echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $data;
}
```

but when i run this from my localhost the `echo $data` is empty it doesnt show anything.
How do i fix this? This is my first time working with cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to get page content
 "

function GetHtmlContents( $url )

```
{
```

$user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0";

```
    $options = array(

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST  =>"GET",        //set request type post or get
        CURLOPT_POST           =>false,        //set to GET
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => $user_agent, //set user agent
        CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie file
        CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      =>"cookie.txt", //set cookie jar
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}    print_r(GetHtmlContents('https://www.facebook.com/events/383049449109054/'));
```

"

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it should work for you.

```
function GetHtmlContents($url){
    echo file_get_contents($url); 
}
```

Read more about `file_get_contents()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: But in your case you are trying to get facebook events. Why don't you try to get facebook events by using facebook graph api ? which can give you all the content you are looking for from this event page.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response, i know i can just use the FB api but since i dont like how facebook treats users privacy wise i dont want to use the fb api :/

Comment: okay then try to use my given code. Tell me if it works for you

Comment: when i run your code i get an fb page that tells me my browser is not supported.. and i need to load the correct html into an DOM element

Comment: I have tried this same for another url and its working for all urls instead of fb page
<?php

echo file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');

Comment: yes correct for other urls it works but not fb and i just need fb urls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187657/discussion-between-abdulrehman-sheikh-and-futurecake).

Comment: You should use fb api otherwise you cannot do this because of fb security reasons.